# sqlalchemy.exc.IntegrityError: (sqlite3.IntegrityError) NOT NULL constraint failed: profile.user_id

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I am new to databases and SQLAlchemy. I currently am making a web app where there are users and each user has profiles they can make. From my knowledge this is a one-to-many relationship. The problem is when I try to make a profile I get the Integrity error and I am not sure why. This is the code in my models file

```
class User(db.Model, UserMixin):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key = True, autoincrement = True)
    username = db.Column(db.String(20), unique = True, nullable = False)
    email = db.Column(db.String(120), unique = True, nullable = False)
    password = db.Column(db.String(60), nullable = False)
    profiles = db.relationship('Profile', backref = 'creator', lazy = True)

    def __repr(self):
        return f"User('{self.username}', '{self.email}')"

class Profile(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key = True)
    profileName = db.Column(db.String(), nullable = False)
    firstName = db.Column(db.String(20), nullable = False)
    lastName = db.Column(db.String(30), nullable = False)
    email = db.Column(db.String(), nullable = False)
    phone = db.Column(db.String(), nullable = False)
    address = db.Column(db.String(), nullable = False)
    address1 = db.Column(db.String(), nullable = True)
    city = db.Column(db.String(), nullable = False)
    state = db.Column(db.String(), nullable = False)
    zipCode = db.Column(db.String(), nullable = False)
    country = db.Column(db.String(), nullable = False)
    cc = db.Column(db.String(16), nullable = False)
    expMonth = db.Column(db.String(2), nullable = False)
    expYear = db.Column(db.String(2), nullable = False)
    cvv = db.Column(db.String(4), nullable = False)
    url = db.Column(db.String(), nullable = False)
    user_id = db.Column(db.Integer(), db.ForeignKey('user.id'), nullable = False)
```

this is the code in my routes file

```
@login_required
def newProfile():  
    form = CheckoutForm()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        profile = Profile(profileName = form.profileName.data, firstName = form.firstName.data, lastName = form.lastName.data, 
        email = form.email.data, phone = form.phone.data, address = form.address.data, address1 = form.address1.data, city = form.city.data,
        state = form.state.data, zipCode = form.zipCode.data, country = form.country.data, cc = form.cc.data, expMonth = form.expMonth.data,
        expYear = form.expYear.data, cvv = form.cvv.data, url = form.url.data, creator = current_user)
        db.session.add(profile)
        db.session.commit()
        flash(f"Profile Created!")
        return redirect(url_for('profiles'))
    return render_template('newProfile.html', title="New Profile", form = form)
```

I am assuming it is something with my profiles and user_id variables, but I can't figure out what. I looked at documentation and looked at some of the solutions on stack overflow but still couldnt get it working. Again sorry if this is a n00b question. I am new to making web apps and using databases so there are a lot of things I am still learning and trying to understand!

Comment: Can you show us the code you are running that gives you the error? The error leads me to believe a user is not created or not committed when trying to save your profile

Comment: just added the code that runs it

Comment: I see `user_id` in your model, but `creator` in `newProfile()`? and if `current_user` is a user object I think you'll want `current_user.id`

Comment: changed newProfile() to have user_id = current_user.id but still get the error. Should I change the backref from creator to something else then? Or is that not really related

Comment: Where is current_user coming from? I don't see any references in newProfile(). I don't think the backref is the issue. You need to have a user created since its a foreign key and it cannot be null/empty

Comment: it is from flask-login https://flask-login.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#flask_login.current_user

Comment: I'm assuming then the user is coming from a `user_loader` function? To debug you could also `print(current_user)` in the very first line of `def newProfile()` it issue is that a user object isn't being passed in